# Checking for Undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined

I was following the below logic to check if a variable is undefined or not:

```
 if (variable==undefined){
////implementation
}
```

But found that for some cases it did not function as expected. So, tried this approach,

```
if(typeof(variable) == "undefined"){
/////implementation
}
```

So which one is most reliable?

Comment: see the questions under the Related section on the right side of the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript)

Comment: SO search *javascript undefined check*: 3745 results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second way is the most reliable but you don't need the parenthesis for the `typeof` operator. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript).

Answer (score 3):

```
if (variableName){
////implementation
}
```

this way is more use full than second option